# Create Chan In TCL for specific app

Tags: tcl, channel, puts

I use an app that has the ability to run TCL the app itself is written in C++ (shorthand 10) I believe that I push it far beyond what it was ever intended to do. As are most programming languages and good tools. This however poses a uniqe issue some of the items that are native to TCL are not included with this so I have to find creative ways to do what I'm looking to accomplish. -Enough of the back story... One of the major drawbacks is that there is no stdout or other regular channels.I know that there is a way to create one but I'm having a hard time.  I have found the following code and am trying to make it work but am getting an error. The file path that I would like to use for the stdout is:

```
#FilePath of output ---> [sh_window exedir]IO_Text/stdout

oo::class create stdout {
    variable var
    constructor {varName} {
        my eval [list upvar \#0 $varName var]
    }
    method initialize {ch mode} {
        if {$mode ne "write"} {error "can't handle reading"}
        return {finalize initialize write}
    }
    method watch {ch events} {
        # Must be present but we ignore it because we do not
        # post any events
    }
    method finalize {ch} {
        my destroy
    }
    method write {ch bytes} {
        append var $bytes
        # Return the empty string, as we are swallowing the bytes
        return ""
    }
}

# Now we create an instance...
set string "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\n"
set ch [chan create write [stdout new $string]]
```

--When this is run I get the following error:

```
chan handler "::oo::Obj12" does not support all required methods
```

The workaround that I am using for the moment is as follows. But I know that this is Horrible!

```
rename puts _puts;
proc puts {WInfo} {
set chan [open "[sh_window exedir]IO_Text/stdout" a+]
_puts $chan $WInfo; close $chan
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few places where you've gone wrong. You *must* support `watch` even if by doing nothing, and you *must* return the number of bytes written from your `write` implementation (luckily, this is trivial for you to do).

This is also a good time to hide the call to `chan create` inside the construction function of the class instance; there's no way to use the object created otherwise, so we might as well squirrel it away. (You *can't* do that in Java without futzing around with factories.)

```
oo::class create stdout {
    variable var
    constructor {varName} {
        set s [list upvar \#0 $varName var]
        namespace eval [namespace current] $s
    }
    method initialize {ch mode} {
        if {$mode ne "write"} {error "can't handle reading"}
        return {finalize initialize write watch}
    }
    method watch {ch events} {
        # Must be present but we ignore it because we do not post any events
    }
    method finalize {ch} {
        my destroy
    }
    method write {ch bytes} {
        append var $bytes
        return [string length $bytes]
    }
    # Magic! Define a method on the 'stdout' class object itself
    self method new {varName} {
        set obj [next $varName]
        return [chan create write $obj]
    }
    # Stop normal code from creating named instances
    self unexport create
}
```

Finally, you call with a strange variable name in your test code — Tcl's *strict* about variable names vs. variable usage — and you may run into problems with testing because Tcl's channels (*except* when going to a terminal) default to fully buffered, which makes no sense in this case.

```
set myString "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\n"
set ch [stdout new myString]
fconfigure $ch -buffering none
puts $ch "Howdy, pardner!"
puts >>$myString<<
```

When I try that, I get this output:

```
>>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
Howdy, pardner!
<<
```

Comment: Also, consider using the [`tcl::chan::variable`](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/virtchannel_base/tcllib_variable.html) package from Tcllib, which basically does all this for you.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an implementation of the mandatory `watch` subcommand as explained in the [refchan documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/refchan.htm#M21). That is why you get the error about not supporting all methods. The example shows a dummy stub that you can copy.

Comment: I looked at that I wasnt sure if the watch was required... for some reason I thought that was just for reading.

Comment: I have added the watch sub command and still get the same error. I have to be missing something, also where is it that I direct the output to the file that it would write to?

Comment: Do you have an event loop active? Either through vwait or running Tk. That is required as well.